# Factoring $x^4-2x^3+2x^2+x+4$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

> I need to show that the polynomial is not irreducible and I am trying to factor the polynomial 
>   $$x^4-2x^3+2x^2+x+4$$

I checked from a calculator that it has a factor but how do I get it by myself?

I tried grouping but It didnt work I got 
$x^2(x^2-2x+2)+x+4$ And I dont know how should I proceed. My guts tell me that it should be of the form:
$(x^2-ax+k)(x^2+bx+l)$, should I just try to figure out the constants by trying out?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit $(x^2 - 3 x + 4) (x^2 + x + 1) $

Comment: Yes thats what the calculators give, but how do I reach it using pen and paper? If there's a technique, I dont know it :)

Comment: @70pr4k Multiply out your ansatz and compare coefficients.

Comment: Note that $(x^2+x+1)^2=x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1$ so its probably going to have a factor of $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: Irreducible over $\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x^4-2x^3+2x^2+x+4$$
$$=(x^2+1)^2-2x^3+x+3$$
$$=(x^2+1)^2-2x(x^2+1)+3x+3$$
$$=(x^2+1)^2+x(x^2+1)-3x^3+3$$
$$=(x^2+1)^2+x(x^2+1)-3(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$
$$=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+1-3x+3)$$
and you are done.

Comment: Is this a particular trick -- or is it more generally applicable to at least a group of quartics?

Comment: @Allawonder, I don't see any trick here. The quadratic -- with the $x^4$ and $2x^2$ terms -- hints towards $(x^2+1)^2.

Comment: Whoever has downvoted my answer, you should justify that in comments.

Comment: I'm not using the word trick derogatorily. Also, I didn't downvote. My main question is whether this can be applied more generally to other quartics. Is this the case?

Comment: @Allawonder, Yes it can be applied in other situations also. For example, in factorising $x^4+2x^3+x^2-1$ (try yourself).

Answer (score 8):

If we can write $$p(x)= q(x)r(x)$$ say in $\mathbb{Z}$ then we can do that also in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ where $m$ is an arbitrary integer $>1$. So there exists $q_1,r_1$ such that

$$p(x)\equiv_m q_1(x)r_1(x)$$ and $$r(x) \equiv_m r_1(x) \;\;\;\wedge\;\;\; q(x) \equiv_m q_1(x)  $$

and we might hope that $r(x) = r_1(x)$ or $q(x) =q_1(x)$.

---

If we try this in your case for mod $2$ we get $$p(x) \equiv_2 x^4+x \equiv_2 x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$$

and we see that $x^2+x+1$ actually divide $p(x)$.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this doesn't work the other direction: there are integer polynomials that factor over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for every $p$ but are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Actually I want to do that, and I don't know why I didn't. Thank you @StevenStadnicki

Comment: Note that it doesn't work for most of the cases. Because in the last line, we could replace $x^2+x+1$ by $x^2+kx+1$ for any odd integer $k$, which is not a factor for any $k\neq 1$. We are apparently guessing a factor.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you just try to solve this like a general quartic equation you get a break: let $x=t+1/2$. Then
$$\begin{align}x^4-2x^4+2x^2+x+4&=\left(t+\frac12\right)^4-2\left(t+\frac12\right)^3+2\left(t+\frac12\right)^2+\left(t+\frac12\right)+4\\
&=t^4+\frac12t^2+2t+\frac{77}{16}\\
&=\left(t^2+at+b\right)\left(t^2-at+c\right)\\
&=t^4+\left(b-a^2+c\right)t^2-a(b-c)t+bc\end{align}$$
So we have
$$\begin{align}b+c&=\frac12+a^2\\
b-c&=-\frac2a\end{align}$$
With solutions
$$\begin{align}2b&=a^2+\frac12-\frac2a\\
2c&=a^2+\frac12+\frac2a\end{align}$$
Then
$$4bc=a^4+a^2+\frac14-\frac4{a^2}=\frac{77}4$$
Which simplifies to
$$a^6+a^4-19a^2-4=0$$
And here is our break: the resolvent cubic has a rational root: $a^2=4$. If we pick $a=2$, then $b=7/4$, $c=11/4$ and
$$\begin{align}x^4-2x^4+2x^2+x+4&=\left(t^2+2t+\frac74\right)\left(t^2-2t+\frac{11}4\right)\\
&=\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+2\left(x-\frac12\right)+\frac74\right)\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-2\left(x-\frac12\right)+\frac{11}4\right)\\
&=\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(x^2-3x+4\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: That is pretty cool. $+1$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rational Root Test to check if there is any real roots. It turns out that there is no such roots of this polynomial. Hence, the conclusion is that there can only be complex roots. By the fundamental theorem of Algebra, we know any non constant single variable polynomial has at least one complex root (including real ones).

As you have mentioned, assume that the polynomial is the product of two quadratic polynomials. Solve them and find constants $a,b,k$ & $l$